# Redirecting visitors to a rel=alternate page - permanent or temporary?

Tags: seo, redirects, rel-alternate

We are rebuilding our travel site to have both en-US and en versions, storing the language/region code in the url as a subfolder. Eg:

```
www.domain.com/africa/botswana (hreflang="x-default")
www.domain.com/en/africa/botswana (hreflang="en")
www.domain.com/en-US/africa/botswana (hreflang="en-US")
```

All pages will be available in all three versions. A visitor landing on the x-default url will have their origin detected via geoip and be redirected to one of the language/region-specific urls.

We plan on offering a site selector (flag dropdown) on each page to let a visitor override the detected origin - this will drop a cookie to remember the preference.

When a visitor does land on a non-specific url and is redirected, should this be a permanent (301) or temporary (302) redirect?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be careful using 301 Moved Permanently if the original URIs are still valid. You risk search engines will unindex them and reindex your site with the redirected URIs only.

I'd rather consider 302 Found or the [307 Temporary Redirect](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21#section-7.4.7) (These are HTTP 1.1). After all that's what you're doing - redirecting this current user temporarily as he requests another translation.

In addition would consider specifying the [canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066) to avoid duplicate content issues.